# Using a nested for loop to append to multiple lists

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I'm trying to loop the Shockley diode equation over three different temperatures (with three different saturation currents), for a range of values of voltage, and then insert these three lots of data into lists.

```py
kb = 1.38E-23
q = 1.602E-19

voltage = np.arange(0.5, 1.02, 0.02)

T = np.array([269, 289.1, 294.5])
Is = np.array([1.707E-14, 6.877E-14, 1.4510E-13])

i269 = []
i284 = []
i294 = []

for i in range(1, len(voltage)):
    for j in range(1, 3):
        I = Is[j] * np.exp((voltage[i] * q) / (kb * T[j]))
        i269.append(I[j[0]])
        i284.append(I[j[1]])
        i294.append(I[j[2]])
```

I know the method I've used here is not syntactically correct but I've written it this way to try to aid my efforts in conveying what it is I'm trying to achieve.

I want to loop through voltage first for j = 0, and append I into i269, then again through voltage for j = 1 and append into i284 etc.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What's the question, just how to make it clear and maintainable?

Answer (score 0):

Note that with your current approach `I` cannot be indexed, as you're simply assigning a value to it. You'd firstly need to define it as a list, and then index it to assign its values to `i269`, `i284` or `i294`:

```
kb = 1.38E-23
q = 1.602E-19

voltage = np.arange(0.5, 1.02, 0.02)

T = np.array([269, 289.1, 294.5])
Is = np.array([1.707E-14, 6.877E-14, 1.4510E-13])

I = [0 for _ in range(len(T))]
i269 = []
i284 = []
i294 = []

for i in range(len(voltage)):
    for j in range(3):
        I[j] = Is[j] * np.exp((voltage[i] * q) / (kb * T[j]))
    i269.append(I[0])
    i284.append(I[1])
    i294.append(I[2])
```

---

However, it is possible to gain improvements in performance by leveraging [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and vectorising the above as:

```
i269, i284, i294 = Is[:,None] * np.exp((voltage * q) / (kb * T)[:,None])
```

---

Lets check the results and have a look at the timings with both approaches:

```
kb = 1.38E-23
q = 1.602E-19

voltage = np.arange(0.5, 1.02, 0.02)

T = np.array([269, 289.1, 294.5])
Is = np.array([1.707E-14, 6.877E-14, 1.4510E-13])

def current_approach(kb, q, voltage, T, Is):
    I = [0 for _ in range(len(T))]
    i269 = []
    i284 = []
    i294 = []

    for i in range(len(voltage)):
        for j in range(3):
            I[j] = Is[j] * np.exp((voltage[i] * q) / (kb * T[j]))
        i269.append(I[0])
        i284.append(I[1])
        i294.append(I[2])
    return i269, i284, i294

def vect_approach(kb, q, voltage, T, Is):
    i269, i284, i294 = Is[:,None] * np.exp((voltage * q) / (kb * T)[:,None])
    return i269, i284, i294
```

---

```
np.allclose(current_approach(kb, q, voltage, T, Is), 
            vect_approach(kb, q, voltage, T, Is))
# True
```

---

```
%timeit current_approach(kb, q, voltage, T, Is)
# 201 µs ± 3.46 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit vect_approach(kb, q, voltage, T, Is)
# 30.9 ns ± 0.647 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

---

Up to a huge **`6,500x`** speedup with the vectorised approach!